# Virtual Box on a 15-inch MacBook ProYosemite with Retina display

Tags: virtualbox, osx-yosemite

I am installing Windows 7 in a 15-inch MacBook Pro Yosemite with Retina display, using a Virtual Box 4.3.28,
Would be possible to see the virtual machine in full screen mode ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of VB do you have? I have 4.3 and OSX Yosemite and was able to fullscreen with View -> Switch for Fullscreen Mode

Answer (score 2):

Yes, navigate to View -> Switch to Fullscreen Mode (or HOST+F)

Comment: unfortunately it has not worked, I guess Virtual Box  is not ready yet for Yosemite with Retina display

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install the Guest Additions.

While in Virtual Box, select the Devices Menu, Insert Guest Additions CD.  This will show up on the Windows Computer section.  Run the installation, reboot and the screen will now be full screen.